# Matrix of p-values from chisq.test

Tags: r

How can I create a matrix of p-values from a `chisq.test` showing all the column names.

My code to get p-values

```
test1 <- summary(xtabs(formula = Pass ~ gender + Dependents, data = TCC))
test1$p.value

test2 <- summary(xtabs(formula = Pass ~ gender + Partner, data = TCC))
test2$p.value

test3 <- summary(xtabs(formula = Pass ~ Dependents + Partner, data = TCC))
test3$p.value
```

Desired output:

```
PASS        Gender     Partner     Dependents
Gender        0        0.0045        0.9182
Partner    0.0045        0           0.0126  
Dependents 0.9182      0.0126          0
```

Comment: If you can provide your data (or a complete subset of your data) using `dput` that will help make the problem reproducible so someone can help you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for that, the data is really big,has 21 variables, in short it has say, 4 columns, gender is male or female, partner is yes or no and dependents is yes or no and response variable is pass or fail, so to find the hypothesis test of independency, i am looking to make a matrix of p-values as we do correlation matrix.

Comment: We need a subset of your data to be able to work through this and post a solution. Small things like data types can have a huge impact on ability to craft a solution that works for you. As posted, you may not get much response on this question :(  but if you provide a subset of your data that's easy for us to drop into our own R sessions, you will probably get an answer relatively quickly. Help us help you! :)